# Visual Basic: Can not access TextBox attribiutes

Tags: vb6

Sorry. i am officially new in Visual Basic.

I have created a TextBox in my form. In "**View Code**" i want to access the `Text attribute`

(I mean TextBox.Text)
,but the object only gives me these 4: `Count,Item,LBound,UBound`

Comment: Post your code, please

Comment: Looks like you have an array there rather than the Textbox class.

Comment: Is this `vb6` or `vb.net`? I know it is tag as `vb.net` but this could be a vb6 problem.

Comment: what if he called it TextBox... that would be a problem, right?

Comment: @Edper yes it is vb6. and sorry for last tag

Comment: @Salman see my answer below. You probably changed the value of Index property of your Textbox that would turn it into a Control Array. Probably you meant to change the TabIndex. Again see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you're changing the `Index` property instead of the `TabIndex` property so that it would become a **control array** thus `UBound`, `LBound`, `Count` and `Item` properties are present.

And i suspect you are using `Visual Basic 6` instead of `VB.Net`.

See link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z8k5by%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) the `VB6` has `Index` property that is for **Control Array**.

Comment: Your master. and again sorry for my unclear question

Answer (score 0):

My guess, without seeing your code is that your syntax is somehow interacting with an array, try this code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.TextBox1.Text = "Hello World"
    End Sub
End Class
```

> Note: The above code represents the default names for a `Form`, a new `TextBox` dragged and dropped onto the designer inside of the form's `Load` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Are you possibly copying and pasting a textbox rather than double clicking the object in the toolbox.  If you look in the name of the object in the properties window you would see txtName(0)